# Mandelbrot set reaches to its limit way too soon

Tags: 3d, mandelbrot, heightmap

im calculating mandelbrot set, with the ability of zooming and printing it to the screen using OpenGL.

as you know mandelbrot set is defined by a rectangle(top right point and bottom left point) and every time i 'zoom in' and 'zoom out' i change the following points by moving the bottom left point to the upper right side and the top right point vice versa.  eventually those 2 points are supposed to meet each other and finish the zooming process.
according to many YOUTUBE movies i can see clearly that some movies allow you to reach to 1000X zoom. when in my program i can hardly reach to X6. while debugging i can see my 2 points, which define the mandelbrot set reach each other `(x1,y1) = (x2,y2)`.
few things :
`(x1,y1) & (x2,y2)` are defined as floats. should i use double instead ?
my mandelbrot is defined by (512X512) points. is that enough? though im not sure it's connected to the problem.

another problem i;m facing is that - im printing the set as an height map(3D set). when each Y component representes the amount of iterations it took a certain point to reach infinity. however each time i zoom in the entire set goes upper and upper to the my camera's positions and eventually my camera is consumed by the set. is there a way to calculate the difference and move the camera away from the set(from the zooming point accordingly?)

the code that calcs the set :

```
double ratiox = instance->foundPointOnHost.x / ((instance->constVal[1][0] - instance->constVal[0][0]));;
            double ratioy = 1-instance->foundPointOnHost.z / ((instance->constVal[1][1] - instance->constVal[0][1]));;
            double xrange = instance->m_GraphConfig.xru-instance->m_GraphConfig.xld;
            double yrange = instance->m_GraphConfig.yru-instance->m_GraphConfig.yld;
            instance->m_GraphConfig.xld += 5*direction*0.005*ratiox*xrange;
            instance->m_GraphConfig.xru -= 5*direction*0.005*(1.-ratiox)*xrange;
            instance->m_GraphConfig.yld += 5*direction*0.005*(1.-ratioy)*yrange;
            instance->m_GraphConfig.yru -= 5*direction*0.005*ratioy*yrange;
```

few things :

instance->FoundPointOnHost = the point i want to zoom in.
instance->constVal = contains the original size of the set (in the begining equals to [xru,yru] [xld,yld])
(xru,yru) = top right points of the set
(xld,yld) = bottom left points of the set

thanks!

Comment: Can you add the code explaining how you update (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) every step?

Comment: Cris Nash: i added the code, thanks!

Comment: i wanted to add also that ratioX represents the percentage of my zooming point to the entire set's size.
for example if im planning on zooming on (0.5,0.3) where my mandelbrot set is 2X2 then ratioX = 0.5/2 and so on

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for including your code! (+1 to the question for making things clear and including all the relevant information).

It shows that your theory for the zoom is correct. At every step, the `xrange` and `yrange` will be scaled by a constant factor (0.975?), and the window will move towards `foundPointOnHost` keeping the same relative position in the window (`ratioX` and `ratioY`). That's definitely the right theory behind the zoom. In practice though, how you're implementing the zoom is going to rapidly accumulate rounding errors because of the way floating-point arithmetic works.

My rules of thumb:

- every time you *multiply or divide* two floating point numbers, you've got a chance of introducing an error whose size is the *last bit* of the *result*;
- but every time you *add or subtract* two floating point numbers, you've got a chance of introducing an error whose size is the *last bit* of the *largest operand*.

Worked example. Suppose you're zooming into (0.5,0.3), and you're already zoomed so `xrange` and `yrange` is about 0.001. And let's say you're using floats (23 bits, about 7 decimal places of accuracy). In your code, when you subtract the two `x` values to recalculate `xrange`, you're subtracting two numbers that are both close to 0.5, which means your error in `xrange` is as much as 0.0000001 - the seventh decimal place of 0.5 - and since the result is about 0.001, your `xrange` is only precise to four decimal places. Then you scale, ratio, and add `xrange` back onto the edges of the window (by an amount that's about 0.00025, now), which again are around 0.5, so that arithmetic operation is only precise to 0.0000001 as well, and the window edges themselves are inaccurate from the previous call. Obviously, things are better if you're using doubles, but again, your `xrange` is losing precision every time through the loop; and by the time you get to the x6 zoom level, perhaps you've lost it all.

The "trick" then is to reduce the number of add and subtracts (currently, you're doing 6 every zoom step), and make sure your errors don't *accumulate* on every iteration. I'd suggest something like the following: keep the `xrange` and `yrange`, and recompute the edges every step: (`ratioX` and `ratioY` are constant, and you might need to work out which one is `ratio` and which is `1-ratio` :)

```
xrange *= 0.975;
xld = foundPointOnHost.x - ratioX * xrange;
xru = foundPointOnHost.x + (1-ratioX) * xrange;
```

and the same for `y`. Even better, compute `xrange` using an operation that won't itself accumulate errors every multiply:

```
// xrange = INITIAL_RANGE * SCALE_FACTOR^frame_number
xrange = exp ( log(INITIAL_RANGE) + frame_number*log(SCALE_FACTOR) );
```

Comment: Great comment Crish!
i have antother 2 small questions for you.
The Zooming depth depands on what variables? the size of my set in pixels? or how many iterations peer each point in the set i preform?
second question is how do i define the zooming depth? in my program, the set is defined as a rectangle, and i decided that i would calc the length of each edge of the rectnagle and eventually would do the following thing : zoom = (OriginalEdge1 * OriginalEdg2) / (NewEdge1*NewEdge2). But that yields wrong results incase you zoom to one of the corener and 1 edge increases faster than the second one

Comment: Your pixels or iteration count shouldn't come into any of these calculations, they're just used for the drawing output - the zoom code should just calculate the rectangle for each frame. Your start and end rectangle need to be in the same aspect ratio, so your zoom is `OriginalEdge1/NewEdge1` == `OriginalEdge2/NewEdge2`. Even if you zoom to a corner (in `foundPointOnHost`), as long as your `xrange` and `yrange` scale at the same rate, and your `foundPointOnHost` keeps the same ratio in the window, you'll be OK.

Comment: well that's what im doing... kinda... but it's impossible for me to get max zoom of X6.. i can only see zoom till the second mandelbrot set. i mean when the main set is zoomed in and i can see the next level.. after it everything goes bluer and my rectangle's points meet each other

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you can you should use `double` instead of `float`.

A float only has 24 bits of mantissa, and when multiplying values at the limit of the precision over and over the extra bits generated just get lost.

FWIW, my WebGL mandelbrot generator (which is restricted to `float` because of WebGL) does manage about 5000x zoom.